# How to make SASS watch for changes out of the main CSS folder?

Tags: css, sass

I'm trying to let my SASS component files out of the main sass folder which is in "src/assets/css/sass",  letting them with their respective components like "src/components/component_1/sass/_index.scss", "src/components/component_2/sass/_index.scss", and so on.

The thing is when I run the command to watch my sass file `sass --watch style.scss:..style.css`, it don't detect any changes that I made in the files that are out off **src/assets/css/sass** even though it was correctly importing the files to the **src/assets/css/sass/style.scss**

In the style.scss I'm importing the component files like this:

```
 @use '../../../components/component_1/sass/index' as cp1;
 @use '../../../components/component_2/sass/index' as cp2;
```

The structure of folder that I'm trying to replace looks like this bellow, look how the name of each component was repeated inside the sass folder (which is exactly what I want to avoid):

```
src
 ┣ assets
 ┃ ┗ css
 ┃ ┃ ┣ sass
 ┃ ┃ ┃ ┣ component_1
 ┃ ┃ ┃ ┃ ┗ _index.scss
 ┃ ┃ ┃ ┣ component_2
 ┃ ┃ ┃ ┃ ┗ _index.scss
 ┃ ┃ ┃ ┗ style.scss
 ┃ ┃ ┣ style.css
 ┗ components
 ┃ ┣ component_1
 ┃ ┃ ┣ js
 ┃ ┃ ┗ index.html
 ┃ ┗ component_2
 ┃ ┃ ┣ js
 ┃ ┃ ┗ index.html
```

I'm trying to achieve this, with each component containing its own sass files.

```
src
 ┣ assets
 ┃ ┗ css
 ┃ ┃ ┣ sass
 ┃ ┃ ┃ ┗ style.scss
 ┃ ┃ ┣ style.css
 ┗ components
 ┃ ┣ component_1
 ┃ ┃ ┣ js
 ┃ ┃ ┣ sass
 ┃ ┃ ┃ ┗ _index.scss
 ┃ ┃ ┗ index.html
 ┃ ┗ component_2
 ┃ ┃ ┣ js
 ┃ ┃ ┣ sass
 ┃ ┃ ┃ ┗ _index.scss
 ┃ ┃ ┗ index.html
```

I'm using the node installation of SASS: 1.49.9 compiled with dart2js 2.16.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found a solution to this, what I needed was to make SASS watch **All** files instead of only the file "style.scss" thus instead of use: `sass --watch style.scss:..style.css` I'm now using this:

```
sass --watch src:.
```

This command will watch all files in the folder "src/" this cold be used too with a single dot (.) to watch all files in the current directory like this:

```
sass --watch .:.
```

This is the same as use

```
sass --watch .:.css
```

which means that the output will be a file .css with the same name of its input.

Honestly I had a hard time trying to set a specific folder and change the name of the output file, so if like me you try to change the name of the command to something like this `sass --watch .:myoutput.css` it will only create a weirdly structure with the name that you passed seted as a folder, creating something like this:
"**myoutput.css**/assets/css/sass/style.css".
In my case especify the watch directory put the output to be the same worked fine like this

```
sass --watch src:src
```

In this case my compiled file went inside the "src" directory and not in the root of the directory.

And remember to use underscore ( **_** ) in every single file that will be imported to the main file, like this "_filesass.scss" the sass compiler will know that this file is only part of other file and won't directly compile it to a file CSS.
In this way my only file that doesn't start with underscore is my main "style.scss" which imports all components files SASS that I need.